# printing strings populated with a loop in C?

Tags: c, arrays, loops

I'm new to C and trying to learn about printing strings and single elements of arrays.

In the main function I have created a char array of 5 characters and am able to print the string. I am also able to print 1 element of the array. This all works fine.

I have then created a function which has a for loop to populate an array with 26 available slots and want to do the same thing, print the whole string and then just print a single element of it.

When my program executes it should print:
Hello
o
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ 
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ (This should print twice, once for the for loop and then once when I try to print the string)
C

However when I try to print the characters this time, I am running into errors and the only difference I can see is the way I have initialised the array. I don't understand the difference and why it is breaking. Is it something to do with the scope of the for loop? I also tried making the char array static but that didn't work either.
Can anyone help with this?

Here's my code

I'm new to C and trying to learn about printing strings and single elements of arrays.

In the main function I have created a char array of 5 characters and am able to print the string. I am also able to print 1 element of the array. This all works fine.

I have then created a function which has a for loop to populate an array with 26 available slots and want to do the same thing, print the whole string and then just print a single element of it.

When my program executes it should print:
Hello
o
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ 
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ (This should print twice, once for the for loop and then once when I try to print the string)
C

However when I try to print the characters this time, I am running into errors and the only difference I can see is the way I have initialised the array. I don't understand the difference and why it is breaking. Is it something to do with the scope of the for loop? I also tried making the char array static but that didn't work either.
Can anyone help with this?

```
void mystring()
{

    char s[26];
    for(char ch = 'A'; ch < 'Z'; ch++)
    {
        int i = 0;
        s[i] = ch;
        printf("%c", s[i]);
        i++;
    }

    printf("\n%s\n", s);
    printf("%c", s[2]);

}

int main()
{
    char mystr[5] = "Hello";
    printf("%s\n", mystr);
    printf("%c\n", mystr[4]);

    mystring();
}
```

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: `int i = 0;` perhaps this scope is wrong

Answer (score 1):

1. There is no `null` terminator for both your "*strings*", I write "*strings*" because they are in effect NOT strings according to the definition of *string* in [c](/questions/tagged/c).
2. Your `i` variable is always `0`, just use a simple formula `ch - 'A'` will give the correct index.
3. Your `char mystr[5] = "hello";` has insufficient space, you need to allocate space for the terminating `'\0'` there too.

To fix your code, you can do this

```
char s[27];
for (int ch = 'A'; ch <= 'Z'; ++ch) {
    s[ch - 'A'] = ch;
}
s[26] = '\0';
```

and,

```
char mystr[6] = "hello";
```

Answer (score 1):

First you should declare the `i` value outside from the `for` loop otherwise the `i++` command has no effect since the `i` will always be `0`.

In C *strings* are arrays with `char` elements so at the end of these containers you should always put the `null` character. So in order to be specific you have to increment by `1` the size of your array (27 not 26) and in the final position of your string, when you are done creating it, `s[26] = '\0';`.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, the major error I see is

```
for(char ch = 'A'; ch < 'Z'; ch++)
    {
        int i = 0;
        s[i] = ch;
        printf("%c", s[i]);
        i++;
    }
```

You want to move the the declaration and initialization statement (`int i = 0`) outside the loop. Right now, it is resetting i to 0 each time (and actually, probably giving you the error since it tries to declare a variable with the same name)

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to comment your code. Hope it helps.

```
void mystring()
{

    char s[26];//you need one extra space for the null terminating char, so it should be "char s[27]"
    for(char ch = 'A'; ch < 'Z'; ch++)//if you want to print 'Z' as well, this should be "ch <= 'Z'", otherwise it stops at 'Y', which is the last char less than 'Z'
    {
        int i = 0;//you should declare this i before the loop, along with your char array. The way you're doing it right now, on every loop iteration you redeclare i and give it the value 0, meaning you're just filling the first position of your char array over and over
        s[i] = ch;
        printf("%c", s[i]);
        i++;
    }
    //s[26] = '\0'; //you should add this line <--remember, strings in C are null-terminated
    printf("\n%s\n", s);
    printf("%c", s[2]);

}

int main()
{
    char mystr[5] = "Hello";//strings in C are null terminated so this should have an extra space "char mystr[6]"
    printf("%s\n", mystr);
    printf("%c\n", mystr[4]);

    mystring();
}
```